# How to differentiate $G(y)=\ln\left[\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate the following expression. My work is below. I'm not sure where my algebra has gone awry. Really appreciate any help. The problem is from James Stewart's Calculus Early Transcendentals 7th Ed. Page 223, Exercise 13.

Please differentiate:
$G(y)=\ln\left[\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right]$

My answer:

1. First, differentiate the natural log.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right)'$$
2. The second term is a quotient rule.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(2y+1)^5{'}(y^2+1)^{1/2}-(y^2+1)^{1/2}{'}(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2*2}}\right)$$
3. Now differentiate the various terms, and recognize chain rule.
   $$(2y+1)^5{'}=(5)(2y+1)^4(2)$$
   $$(y^2+1)^{1/2}{'}=(\frac{1}{2})(y^2+1)^{-1/2}(2y)$$
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4(y^2+1)^{1/2}-(y)(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1}}\right)$$
4. Simplify the expression. First, I move $(y^2+1)^{1/2}$ below the denominator.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4-(y)(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{-1/2}(y^2+1)^{1}}\right)$$
5. Combine the denominator terms.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4-(y)(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right)$$
6. Multiply the first term in the expression (the complex fraction term) by the reciprocal of the denominator to eliminate the complex fraction.
   $$G'(y)=\left((1)*\frac{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}{(2y+1)^5}\right)\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4-(y)(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right)$$
7. Multiply both of these terms. Note that $(y^2+1)^{1/2}$ is in both the numerator and denominator and therefore cancel.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{(y^2+1)^{1/2}[(10)(2y+1)^4-(y)(2y+1)^5]}{(2y+1)^5(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right)$$
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4-(y)(2y+1)^5}{(2y+1)^5}\right)$$
8. Now to cancel the $(2y+1)^x$ terms like so:
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4}{(2y+1)^5}\right)-\left(\frac{(y)(2y+1)^5}{(2y+1)^5}\right)$$
   $$G'(y)=[(10)(2y+1)^{4-5}]-[(y)(2y+1)^{5-5}]$$
   $$G'(y)=[(10)(2y+1)^{-1}]-[(y)(2y+1)^{0}]$$
   $$G'(y)=[(10)(2y+1)^{-1}]-(y)$$
9. Exponent property on $(2y-1)^{-1}$
   $$G'(y)=\frac{(10-y)}{(2y+1)^{1}}$$
   $$G'(y)=\frac{(10-y)}{(2y+1)}$$

The textbook answer is:
$$G'(y)=\frac{10}{2y+1}-\frac{y}{y^2+1}$$

It looks like I'm missing a term. But I'm not sure how. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you lost a term in step 3, at the final line, when plugging in the chain rule differential of the right term of the numerator.

Comment: Also huge props on writing this all out neatly with MathJax (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in **Step 4.**

> First, I move $(y^2+1)^{1/2}$ below the denominator.

Its not possible to move only one term from the one part of numerator. Unless you take it common from all terms of numerator.

Hope its clear now.

Comment: Once try if still have some problem. Let me know please.

Comment: I didn't know that. Your answer was the most helpful because it explains why that move can't be made. I feel I've made this mistake many times in my past. Thank you.

Comment: Mine pleasure bro.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate your effort to type out all the calculations. But I think you are doing "too much". A little bit of reflection on   properties of the logarithm function might save you lots of time.

One could also introduce some notations to avoid repeatedly writing long algebraic expressions:
$$
u(y)=2y+1,\quad v(y)=y^2+1\tag{1}
$$
Then 
 $$
G(y)=\ln\biggr[\dfrac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\biggr]
=5\ln u-\frac{1}{2}\ln v$$
Now it should be rather clear that
$$
G'(y)=5\cdot \frac{u'}{u}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{v'}{v}.
$$

---

Even if you want to stick to your original calculations, (1) frees you from keeping writing $(2y+1)$ and $(y^2+1)$ again and again.

Comment: This is an excellent answer but I think it is worth showing op where their original mistake is. Doing it the brute force way is not bad practice for quotient + chain rule and it would be helpful for them to know where they went wrong, if only for practice.

Answer (score 1):

Edits made here:

1. First, differentiate the natural log.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right)'$$
2. The second term is a quotient rule.
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(2y+1)^5{'}(y^2+1)^{1/2}-(y^2+1)^{1/2}{'}(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2*2}}\right)$$
3. Now differentiate the various terms, and recognize chain rule.
   $$(2y+1)^5{'}=(5)(2y+1)^4(2)$$
   $$(y^2+1)^{1/2}{'}=(\frac{1}{2})(y^2+1)^{-1/2}(2y)$$
   $$G'(y)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}}\right)\left(\frac{(10)(2y+1)^4(y^2+1)^{1/2}-(y)\color{red}{(y^2+1)^{-1/2}}(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1}}\right)$$

I think there is your mistake so I'll let you continue from there :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I couldn't understand why that move is invalid until Kanwaljit explained.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the derivative of this function will be a lot easier if you simplify it first as far as possible using properties of logarithms:
$$G(y)=\ln\left[\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right]=\ln(2y+1)^5-\ln(y^2+1)^{1/2}=5\ln(2y+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y^2+1).$$
Then
$$G'(y)=\left[5\ln(2y+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y^2+1)\right]'=5\cdot\frac{1}{2y+1}\cdot2-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{y^2+1}\cdot2y=\frac{10}{2y+1}-\frac{y}{y^2+1}.$$

Comment: This is a fantastic suggestion because that is clearly a lot less work! I think going forward I'll try solving problems as you said, simplify first. Also as Jack has posted, using shorthand can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way (might be easier)

$$G(y)=\ln\left[\frac{(2y+1)^5}{(y^2+1)^{1/2}}\right]$$

$$ G(y)= \ln((2y+1)^5)- \ln((y^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}) $$

$$ G'(y) = \frac{1}{(2y+1)^5} \cdot 5(2y+1)^4\cdot2-\frac{1}{(y^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}(y^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cdot 2y$$

$$ G'(y) =\frac{10}{2y+1}-\frac{y}{y^2+1} $$